# How to still get data from a table in a join query if there is nothing to match in the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which contains two tables,

`snm_content` and `snm_fields_values`

`snm_content` has numerous fields, only `id` is relevant here, and `snm_fields_values` has three fields, `item_id`, `field_id` and `value`

the field `id` of `snm_content` is the same as the field `item_id` of `snm_fields_values`.

I want to get all data from `snm_content` and join `snm_fields_values` but also retrieve data from `snm_content` if nothing can be joined. So if there is no matching `item_id` in `snm_fields_values` then still get the data from `snm_content`.

The problem is with the following query I only get results from `snm_content` if there is a matching `item_id` in `snm_fields_values`

```
SELECT cnt.*,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end) as service_icon
FROM snm_fields_values f
JOIN snm_content cnt
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE cnt.catid = 9
AND cnt.state = 1
ORDER BY cnt.ordering
```

If no `item_id` exists for an `id` in `snm_content` nothing is retrieved from `snm_content`. How can I fix that? I've tried switching the order of retrieving data but this had the same result.

Comment: Your have a `SUM()` but no `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT cnt.*,
       MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end) as service_icon
FROM snm_content cnt LEFT JOIN
     snm_fields_values f
     ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE cnt.catid = 9 AND cnt.state = 1
GROUP BY cnt.id
ORDER BY cnt.ordering;
```

Note that this adds `GROUP BY` so you get one row per group in the content table.

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cnt.*,
       (SELECT MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end)
        FROM snm_fields_values f
        WHERE cnt.id = f.item_id
       ) as service_icon
FROM snm_content cnt 
WHERE cnt.catid = 9 AND cnt.state = 1
GROUP BY cnt.id
ORDER BY cnt.ordering;
```